# Reading license plate from image using OpenCV Python and Tesseract

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, tesseract

I have a problem because I have separate registrations for photos. Now I would like to get the registration number from the photo. Unfortunately, the effectiveness of the code I wrote is very low and I would like to ask for help in achieving greater efficiency. any tips?

In the first phase, the photo looks like this

[image]

Then transform the photo to gray and only the black color contrasts

```
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

# define range of black color in HSV
lower_val = np.array([0,0,0])
upper_val = np.array([179,100,130])

# Threshold the HSV image to get only black colors
mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_val, upper_val)
```

receives

[image]

What can I add or do to improve the effectiveness of the program. is there a way for the program to retrieve registrations a bit? Will this help

```
configr = ('-l eng --oem 1 --psm 6-c tessedit_char_whitelist=ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789')

text = pytesseract.image_to_string(mask,lang='eng', config=configr)

print(text)
```

Answer (score 6):

Here's an approach:

1. **Color threshold to extract black text.** We load the image, convert to HSV colorspace, define a lower and upper color range, and use `cv2.inRange()` to color threshold and obtain a binary mask
2. **Perform morphological operations.** Create a kernel and perform morph close to fill holes in the contours.
3. **Filter license plate contours.** Find contours and filter using bounding rectangle area. If a contour passes this filter, we extract the ROI and paste it onto a new blank mask.
4. **OCR using Pytesseract.** We invert the image so desired text is black and throw it into Pytesseract.

---

Here's a visualization of each step:

Obtained mask from color thresholding + morph closing

[image]

Filter for license plate contours highlighted in green

[image]

Pasted plate contours onto a blank mask

[image]

Inverted image ready for Tesseract

[image]

Result from Tesseract OCR

> PZ 689LR

Code

```
import numpy as np
import pytesseract
import cv2

pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r"C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe"

# Load image, create blank mask, convert to HSV, define thresholds, color threshold
image = cv2.imread('1.png')
result = np.zeros(image.shape, dtype=np.uint8)
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
lower = np.array([0,0,0])
upper = np.array([179,100,130])
mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower, upper)

# Perform morph close and merge for 3-channel ROI extraction
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (3,3))
close = cv2.morphologyEx(mask, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel, iterations=1)
extract = cv2.merge([close,close,close])

# Find contours, filter using contour area, and extract using Numpy slicing
cnts = cv2.findContours(close, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
for c in cnts:
    x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
    area = w * h
    if area < 5000 and area > 2500:
        cv2.rectangle(image, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (36,255,12), 3)
        result[y:y+h, x:x+w] = extract[y:y+h, x:x+w] 

# Invert image and throw into Pytesseract
invert = 255 - result
data = pytesseract.image_to_string(invert, lang='eng',config='--psm 6')
print(data)

cv2.imshow('image', image)
cv2.imshow('close', close)
cv2.imshow('result', result)
cv2.imshow('invert', invert)
cv2.waitKey()
```